# Adjust Brightness of External Display Mac Programmatically

Tags: objective-c, macos, screen-brightness, external-display

Does anyone know of a way to change the brightness of an external display connected to a mac through Objective-C? (Like an Apple Thunderbolt Display or LED Cinema Display?) I have seen answers for adjusting the primary screen's brightness, but not a secondary screen.

Thanks.